# Looking for children’s scary story/anthology book, published before 2001, with a girl taken away by owl creatures

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, anthology-book

The only story I can remember in the book was about a girl who was warned not to open/look out of her window at night or she would be taken. And she was taken by scary owl creatures that carried her away in the wind. Book was a hardcover, with colorful and terrifying illustrations for every story, it may or may not have been a collection of foreign tales but I can’t remember any more.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the cover art, or at least the colour of the cover?  What made them "owl creatures" and not just owls?